# Inspecting/Modifying RxJS Observable instance

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular-httpclient

I have the following typescript method

```
private processRequest<T>(request: Observable<T>, ...): Promise<T> {...}
```

*request* is an HttpClient Observable

```
processRequest(httpClient.get(url, ...));
...
processRequest(httpClient.post(url, ...));
...
```

- Is it possible to retrieve **url** inside processRequest? If yes how? If not why?
- Is it possible to change **url** inside processRequest? If yes how? If not why?

Comment: No, and no. This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: @IngoBürk Why no? What do you mean with XY problem?

Comment: "Why no?" — Because that is the answer to your two questions.

Comment: @IngoBürk - questions changed. Also, please clarify what you mean with XY problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to retrieve url inside processRequest? [...] If not why?

In the general sense, in `f(g(x))`, `f` cannot access `x`, as it can only see what `g` returns, and that return value doesn't have to have knowledge over `x` at all. Consider `g = u => 42` as a simple example of a function that doesn't retain the information about its input.

It *would* work if the return value retains that information. For example, for `g = u => u` (the identity function), `f` would of course know `x` because that's exactly what gets passed to it. This requires `f` to have this specific knowledge, though.

Since `HttpClient#get` returns `Observable`, this isn't the case here, though. This can be understood intuitively if you think about the fact that `url` is information specific to the logic of `HttpClient`, while `Observable` stems from RxJs which doesn't know anything about Angular. More directly, it can be seen by simply inspecting `Obervable`'s type.

> Is it possible to change url inside processRequest? [...] If not why?

This is now obvious, but you can't change what you can't access.

Comment: Observable<> is not a function, is an object. What we do with it is calling methods, like  subscribe, which act using internal status. In this case, the url must be buried somewhere in the status. In fact, we can provide an interceptor for the outgoing request (which is called after the Observable is created), which receives the full request. This means that that information is in the object and can be accessed at some level.

Comment: But `#get` is a function. Anyway, observables are much closer to functions than you think. What actually happens with the URL is that it gets closed over in a function passed to the observable. No, you cannot access it. If you're convinced that you can, why ask this question? In that case just debug the object in the console and figure out which property it is.

Comment: Interceptors, by the way, might be the answer to the question you didn't ask. But you asked a very specific question, and the answer to that is that it isn't possible.